# How to write unit test case for button onClick event using Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

In the following code I tried to unit test onClick event of button <button data-testid="btn" onClick={()=>Add(value)}>Add part using jest. I am not getting specifically how to test onClick event when it is invoking a function in component.

***App.js***

```
function App(){
   const[value,setValue] = useState('')
   const[list,setList] = useState([])

   function Add(el){
      let updatedList = [...list,el]
      setList(updatedList)
   }

   return(
<div>
   <input data-testid="inpField" type="text" onChange={(e)=>setValue(e.target.value)}
   <button data-testid="btn" onClick={()=>Add(value)}>Add</button>
   {list.map((post,index) => <li key={index}>{post}</li>)}
</div>
)
```

I tried with the following approach but I am getting error -
Expected number of calls: >=1 but received number of calls :0

***App.test.js***

```
test('btn click',()=>{
const Add = jest.fn()
render(<App/>)
const button = screen.getByTestId('btn')
fireEvent.click(button)
expect(Add).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Assume all necessary imports have done.
P.S.:- I don't want to use enzyme until and unless there are no options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real reason why it's showing `Expected number of calls: >=1 but received number of calls :0` because the mock function you have created is never invoked. To invoke this mock function you should pass it as a prop to App component like this:

```
function App({Add}){
   const[value,setValue] = useState('')
   const[list,setList] = useState([])

   return(
<div>
   <input data-testid="inpField" type="text" onChange={(e)=>setValue(e.target.value)}
   <button data-testid="btn" onClick={()=>Add(value)}>Add</button>
   {list.map((post,index) => <li key={index}>{post}</li>)}
</div>
)
```

App.test.js:

```
test('btn click',()=>{
const Add = jest.fn()
render(<App Add={Add}/>)
const button = screen.getByTestId('btn')
fireEvent.click(button)
expect(Add).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Now this test case will pass.

But since as far as I can think you want to test onClick method to add item to the list. So the modified tests case will be like this:

```
test('btn click',()=>{
render(<App/>)
const inputField = screen.getByTestId('inpField');
fireEvent.change(inputField, { target: { value: 'New Item #1' } });

const button = screen.getByTestId('btn')
fireEvent.click(button)

expect(screen.getByText('New Item #1')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

This lets you check whether your on-button click logic is working as expected. Here I first provided some input to the text field and then clicked on the button after that I checked if the input I provided was present in the document or not.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked never thought to link with crossfield and check in the document. Will you please ping me on telegram @kartikdolas97. I have one more doubt that if a button only changes state then how to write its unit test case?

Comment: You can ask it on SO